# Remove URLs from text with regex, except current domain

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to preg replace a string and remove from it all URLs which do not contain current domain.

So far I got this regex, but it does not exclude mydomain. What I'm doing wrong?
`http[s]?:\/\/[w]{0,3}\.{0,1}((?<!mydomain)[^\.].*)`

Expected input and output:
`http://regex101.` => should match
`http://www.regex101.` => should match
`https://regex101.` => should match
`https://www.regex101.` => should match
`https://www.mydomain.` => **should not match**, but it does

https://regex101.com/r/kGil9O/1

I've read several SO questions/answers and either they don't work for my case, either are somehow different. When answer, please explain where I was wrong so I could be better next time. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the lookbehind in a wrong way, it checks the text *on the left*, and you try to match `www.` before the lookbehind. `www.` is not `mydomain`.

Use a lookahead:

```php
https?:\/\/(?!(?:www\.)?mydomain)(?:www\.)?([^.].*)
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/EkIQ5L/2)

**EXPLANATION**

```php
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  http                     'http'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  s?                       's' (optional (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  :                        ':'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \/                       '/'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \/                       '/'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture (optional
                             (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      www                      'www'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \.                       '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )?                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    mydomain                 'mydomain'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (optional
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    www                      'www'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \.                       '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )?                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^.]                     any character except: '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
```

Answer (score 2):

You get all the matches with the pattern that you tried, as the negative lookbehind asserts if `mydomain` is not directly to the left after matching for example `https://` or `https://www` which is always true.

You can optionally match `www\.` using a possessive quantifier followed by a negative lookahead:

```
^https?://(?:www\.)?+(?!mydomain\.)\S+$
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `https?://` Match the protocol with optional `s` and `://`
- `(?:www\.)?+` Optionally match `www.` and use a possessive quantifier to not backtrack when matched
- `(?!mydomain\.)` Negative lookahead, assert not `mydomain.` directly at the right from the current position
- `\S+` Match 1+ times any non whitspace char
- `$` End of string

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4Onl0N/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/ghZiA)

Example

```
$strings = [
    "http://regex101.",
    "http://www.regex101.",
    "https://regex101.",
    "https://www.regex101.",
    "https://www.mydomain.",
    "https://mydomain."
];
$pattern = "~^https?://(?:www\.)?+(?!mydomain\.)\S+$~";
foreach ($strings as $s) {
    if (preg_match($pattern, $s)) {
        echo "Match: $s" . PHP_EOL;
    } else {
        echo "No match: $s" . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Output

```
Match: http://regex101.
Match: http://www.regex101.
Match: https://regex101.
Match: https://www.regex101.
No match: https://www.mydomain.
No match: https://mydomain.
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Although it's more complete than the best answer chosen, the first sentence in best answer made 'the click' in my mind. Thanks again!